# how to get foreign id's from two different tables and store in an another table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables called user, user_profile and notes

user.php contains

```
id   name  email 
1    sam   sam@dd.com
2    jen   jj@sss.org
```

user_profile.php,

```
id  user_id  fname   lname
1    1        ss      aa
2    2        ww      ed
```

notes.php

```
id  user_id  user_profile_id  note   file
1    1        1               demo    aa.pdf
2    2        2               test     aa.jpg
```

NotesController

```
 public function store_notes()
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        "note" => ['required'],
        "file" => ['required','file'],
    ]);

    // dd($data);
    auth()->user()->userprofile()->notes()->create($data);

    return redirect('users');
}
```

I use this way to insert all details which I want to insert in notes table but I get the following error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::notes()
```

this is my user model

```
public function notes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
}
```

my user_profile model

```
 public function notes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Note','user_profile_id');
}
```

and my notes model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function userprofile()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserProfile');
}
```

actually my point is that, I have to create notes and files in notes table  also insert user_id and user_profile_id in notes table. I know how to use two tables with relations but dont know when it comes to three.. **[NOTE: I already use a relation between user and userprofile during the development of this  sample project it works fine]**
If anyone knows the answer please help me to figure it out the issue... Advance greetings..

Comment: Why do you need the `user_profile_id` column in your `notes` table? It should be enough to just create a relation between a user (which can only have one profile) and the note and you should be ready to go. If you fetch a note and need the profile, just fetch it via [nested relations](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: thank you buddy ....I must rethink about it ..

Comment: Try `auth()->user()->userprofile->notes()->create($data);`

Comment: not worked the above method but as Dan said I didnt want user_profile_jid..thank  you for your response